# Converting an Integer array to a char array, with every 3 digit per integer

Tags: c, arrays, char, integer, microcontroller

I want to convert an array that's been generated through measuring pressure.
So I got an Integer array, like this, I will use 10 samples for now but it will probably become 20 values when it's finished: `uint16_t ADCsample[10]= { 245, 332, 124, 98, 5, 156, 68, 199, 2, 105}`

As you can see the values range from 0-350, no negative values.
The output that I have to get it something like this: `outputStr = {2,4,5,3,3,2,1,2,4,0,9,8,0,0,5,1,5,6,0,6,8,1,9,9,0,0,2,1,0,5}`

So all the integer values are seperated and put into a new array so `ADCsample[0] = {245}` becomes `outputStr[0-2] = {2,4,5}`. But samples with one or two digits have to get the value 0 infront, this is to make the output have a constant length.

For example: `ADCsample[4] = {5}` becomes `outputStr[12-14]={0,0,5}`

I will need to send this data through to a server with only a SMS, which has a character restriction of 160 characters or something. So I will have to send the full outputStr at once. Also all the calculation are done on the Microcontroller MSP430G2553 so it has to be efficient and not use to much memory.

Any tips or code examples to help me started, I am a real novice at this so I don't know many functions of the built-in library? Can I use the sprintf() or other functions or will this use to much memory?

Comment: You need actual characters `{'2','4','5','3','3','2',...}`, not special non-printable characters `{2,4,5,3,3,2,...}`, right?

Comment: `sprintf` with `%03d`.. Then subtract `'0'` from each.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `sprintf` may be a bit too expensive on a microcontroller with only 500 bytes of RAM.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yh I need actual characters so I can print them through the print function that I got, this function can normally print all the characters in an array at once

Comment: So if you need characters then don't subtract `'0'`... but yeah, 0.5Kb of RAM s a serious constraint.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yh indeed, it has been a big struggle but nice to find some work arounds and learn some new ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working and does what you want :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned short ADCsample[10]= { 245, 332, 124, 98, 5, 156, 68, 199, 2, 105};
    char outputStr[31];

    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        outputStr[(i * 3)] = ADCsample[i] / 100 + '0';
        outputStr[(i * 3) + 1] = (ADCsample[i] / 10) % 10 + '0';
        outputStr[(i * 3) + 2] = ADCsample[i] % 10 + '0';
    }
    outputStr[30] = '\0';
    printf("output : %s\n", outputStr);
    return 0;
}
```

I added a printf to show the result.
outputStr's size should be your int array's size * 3 + 1 for this to work.
Also the for condition should be changed according to you int array's size.

Comment: Also, if there is no problem with using sprintf, a similar more compact solution is `for (i=0; i<SAMPLES; i++) sprintf(outputStr+i*3,"%03d\0",ADCsample[i]);`

Comment: You didn't initialize `i`.  Why not use a `for` loop?

Comment: Oh yeah that's wrong! I'll edit this now. And yeah, a for loop would be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain three characters from `uint16_t` with simple math operations:

```
uint16_t val = ...;
char hundredsDigit = (val / 100) + '0';
char tensDigit = ((val / 10) % 10) + '0';
char onesDigit = (val % 10) + '0';
```

This will produce zeros when hundreds and/or tens digits are missing.

> I need actual characters so I can print them through the print function that I got, this function can normally print all the characters in an array at once.

If you are looking to print this using functions for printing strings, you need to null-terminate the result. Add an extra `char` at the end, and set it to zero.

Comment: This helps me with processing the integers now I need some help with how I will add it to an array.

Comment: @MartijnGielen Go through the `ADCsample` one-by-one, using index `i`, and add the results to your output array three at a time, using indexes `3*i`, `3*i+1`, and `3*i+2`.

Comment: @Olaf Asking questions without posting code is not against the site's rules. Starting with embedded development may be overwhelming, especially on your own. I tend to cut embedded newcomers some slack, unlike, say, to Java newcomers, who have less excuses to ask simple questions without code due to availability of tutorials. You are 100% right about posting duplicates, though, especially to questions that have multiple perfectly valid answers. There's also no excuse for rude comments, I flagged them for mod's attention.

Answer (score 0):

For a given number, you can get each digit as follows:

```
d1 = num / 100;
d2 = (num % 100) / 10;
d3 = num % 10;
```

The first calculation does integer division by 100, effectively dropping the 1's and 10's digits leaving you with the 100's digit.

The second takes the remainder of dividing by 100, leaving a value from 0 to 99, then dividing the result by 10 which drops the 1's digit and leaves you the 10's digit.

The third takes the remainder of dividing by 100, leaving a value from 0 to 9.